# Function that will plot all columns of the data in a given number of different figures.

Tags: matlab, plot

thank you for your helps.

I am trying to create a function in MATLAB that plots all the data I have into different figures depending on how many I tell it to create.
For example if i ask for plot(data,5) where my data is 30 columns, it should produce 5 figures, each having 6 of my columns plotted. First figure containing 1~6th columns, next containing 7~12...etc.

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: Take a look at Matlab's [`subplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html).

Comment: Agreed with @Schorsch. `subplot` is likely what you want. I suggest trying it and if you're stuck come back here to ask for help :)